# Dark android theme in RN?

Tags: android, react-native

I'm new to Android and I'm trying to get the android 'dark' theme which will work in all Android versions. Theres a lot of information about this and I'm not sure how to interpret it:

- Holo isn't really used anymore
- Android 6 doesn't support dark theme?
- There is Material light/dark

How can I get a dark theme (for `Alert` and such), so that it is compatible with all versions of Android API > 16?

Comment: Awesome! How do I change the blue color?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you can use `Theme.AppCompat` for dark theme and to answer your other question you should use within your style

```
    <item name="colorAccent">@color/accentColor</item>
    <item name="colorPrimary">@color/primaryColor</item>
    <item name="colorPrimaryDark">@color/darkPrimaryColor</item>
```

to change the default `accent`, `primary` and `darkPrimary` color